# How to break bootstrap table in mobile?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a responsive table that collapses cells into rows on mobile. I'm trying to accomplish this with bootstrap display utility classes but can't find examples on how to exactly use them.

```
<table class='table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover'>
  <tr>
    <td class="d-table-row d-sm-table-cell">inline normally, full width on mobile</td>
    <td class="d-table-row d-sm-table-cell">Nama</td>
    <td class="d-table-row d-sm-table-cell">Email</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Demo kind of does it, but the cells break down in ugly manner and lose their paddings etc. Is there a better way and markup how to do it?

https://codepen.io/clientagency/pen/GRJKmyK

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't offer this functionality, though they do allow tables to scroll horizontally on small screens (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables)

Comment: Datatables can accomplish this using Javascript: https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/

Comment: For a CSS/HTML only solution, you'd probably need two tables, one visible on large screens with rows and columns, and one visible on small screens with only rows.

Comment: Yeah too bad... Separate tables might be a feasible idea! d-block d-sm-table-cell seems to pretty much do what I wanted too. Not sure if its semantically ok...